# avoid url manipulation in jsf

Tags: url, jsf, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I've searched all day long but didn't find any answer to my problem,
I want to pass a parameter while changing views, to a viewscoped bean, but I don't wnat it to apear in the url, I tried to use pretty faces but didn't get what I want, and what I want is for the url parameter to not appear in order to avoid url manipulation.
any help of any kind would be appreciated, but for RTFM advisers, please tell me which manual :D
Thanks

Comment: Then don't pass it in the url but in a session scoped bean or start encrypting thrre param

Comment: I don't want to use @sessionscope  a lot, I don't want it to make the app too slow and have memory issues with all objects created for every use and that are keeped during the session

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, this did the trick for me:
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("car", car);


Car car = (Car) 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("car");